# Keep alive using SIP in .net

Tags: .net, sip, ice

I am creating an application where I need to implement SIP protocol in .NET. We have Client-Server setup where client keeps on sending keep alive message to server. We can only use SIP protocol or any other protocol which is support with ICE.

Could some one help me in implementing this. I don't have much idea about these protocols but I know .net very well. Some sample code would be of great help.

Comment: Implementing it yourself might take time, why don't you buy an existing implementation ?
http://www.independentsoft.de/sip/index.html
You may find other/open source libs with google.

Answer (score 0):

[draft-ief-sip-outbound](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-sip-outbound-20) is what you're looking for. This draft describes keep-alive techniques in section 3.5: you can use CRLF pairs for connection-oriented transports (like TCP), or [STUN](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5389.txt) for connectionless transports (like UDP).